# MySQL - SELECT : count results according current day with interval steps - default count value

Tags: mysql

I have a message log table, containing different types of logs.
As I'm not so keen with MySQL, I would like some advice from the more experienced MySQL profiles :)

I'm looking for a SQLQuery to COUNT the AMOUNT OF MESSAGE logs with INTERVAL of 1 HOUR, for the current day.

When there are no results for that interval, the default should be set as '0'.

```
Created                Message       
-----------------------------------------------
2016-11-07 01:42:06     "Message content here"
2016-11-07 04:10:04     "Message content here"
2016-11-07 12:10:04     "Message content here"
2016-11-07 13:45:24     "Message content here"
2016-11-07 16:22:54     "Message content here"
2016-11-07 17:11:54     "Message content here"
2016-11-07 19:23:54     "Message content here"
2016-11-07 20:15:54     "Message content here"
2016-11-07 20:51:54     "Message content here"
2016-11-07 20:51:57     "Message content here"
2016-11-07 20:51:58     "Message content here"
2016-11-07 20:51:59     "Message content here"
2016-11-07 20:52:05     "Message content here"
2016-11-07 21:02:05     "Message content here"
```

The expected return should be something like this, so I could visualize the result set as graph data.

```
2016-11-07 01:00:00 | 1
2016-11-07 02:00:00 | 0
2016-11-07 03:00:00 | 0
2016-11-07 04:00:00 | 1
2016-11-07 05:00:00 | 0
2016-11-07 06:00:00 | 0
2016-11-07 07:00:00 | 0
2016-11-07 08:00:00 | 0
2016-11-07 09:00:00 | 0
2016-11-07 10:00:00 | 0
2016-11-07 11:00:00 | 0
2016-11-07 12:00:00 | 1
2016-11-07 13:00:00 | 1
2016-11-07 14:00:00 | 0
2016-11-07 15:00:00 | 0
2016-11-07 16:00:00 | 1
2016-11-07 17:00:00 | 1
2016-11-07 18:00:00 | 0
2016-11-07 19:00:00 | 1
2016-11-07 20:00:00 | 6
2016-11-07 21:00:00 | 1
2016-11-07 22:00:00 | 0
2016-11-07 23:00:00 | 0
2016-11-07 00:00:00 | 0
```

Thanks!

Comment: Handle the logic of missing results in whatever application you're using to graph the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will list only hours where some traffic appeared

```
SELECT
 date_format(Created, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00'),
 count(Message)
FROM message_log 
GROUP BY date_format(Created, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00');
```

To list also "empty" hours with zeros you can use something like that:

```
SET @starttime = '2015-10-10 01:00:00';
SET @endtime   = '2016-01-01 12:00:00'; 

SET @starttime_h = date_format( @starttime , '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00');

SET @hours_count = TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, @starttime, @endtime) + 1;

SELECT hours.hour, COUNT(message_log.Message) FROM
( SELECT @starttime_h + INTERVAL ( (a.n) + (b.n<<4) + (c.n<<8) + (d.n<<12)) HOUR as hour
FROM  (select 0 as n union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9 union select 10 union select 11 union select 12 union select 13 union select 14 union select 15) a
  cross join (select 0 as n union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9 union  select 10 union select 11 union select 12 union select 13 union select 14 union select 15) b
  cross join (select 0 as n union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9 union  select 10 union select 11 union select 12 union select 13 union select 14 union select 15) c
  cross join (select 0 as n union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9 union  select 10 union select 11 union select 12 union select 13 union select 14 union select 15) d
WHERE (a.n) + (b.n<<4) + (c.n<<8) + (d.n<<12) <= @hours_count ) hours LEFT JOIN 
message_log  ON (hours.hour = date_format(message_log.Created, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00')) 
WHERE hours.hour BETWEEN @starttime AND @endtime 
GROUP BY hours.hour;
```

Comment: This does not foresee a solution for the 'empty slots'. This only shows the timeframes where there is a result

Comment: It has no zero hours. But adding that using mysql fatures will be quite painful.

Comment: That's less of a problem, the problem is more that the 'empty' time slots should show '0'. Is this possible straight with MySQL?

Comment: In that case you will need to have one more table which will contain one row per hour. And select from there +left joining query above by hour. There is a ways to construct such a table on the fly, but they are rather complicated (query will be like 40 lines long).

Comment: added improved version